# Creating new Equipment combo packs. DB Design or SQL (Alter Table, Order By, Select)

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, database-design

I'm currently working on a basic database for Orders from customers. My issue is fields in one table (call it **EquipmentPerOption**) correspond to records in another table (**Equipment**). In theory adding a record to **Equipment** should add a new Column to **EquipmentPerOption** with the name of the new record.

For example:

```
**Equipment Table**
     Equipment     Price
       Hose        $1.00 
       Shovel      $2.00 
       Hoe         $3.00 

**Equipment per Option Table**
    OrderOption  Hose  Shovel  Hoe
    1             1      0      2
    2             3      2      1
    3             0      1      3
    4             1      1      1
```

So basically I now have a button on a menu which takes me to an Add New Record screen for **Equipment**. How do I make it so that when I've finished adding the new record for Equipment it appears on the **EquipmentPerOption** table as a new Column? Ideally this:

```
    OrderOption  Hose  Shovel  Hoe  (New Equipment)
    1             1      0      2         0 
    2             3      2      1         0
    3             0      1      3         0
    4             1      1      1         0
```

I've been messing around with SQL and have come up with this as an SQL code for a query that will run after clicking a "Check" button at the bottom of the Equipment Form. (Obviously it will save the record before running the query)

```
 ALTER TABLE EquipmentPerOption
    Add
    SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM
      ( SELECT TOP (1) *
        FROM Equipment
        ORDER BY created_date DESC) Short Interger
```

So my question is why is this code wrong? And how do I fix it to achieve the desired outcome? Or have I set up the database wrong and should just start again with a different structure for the tables?

Comment: When you find the database structure needs to change when you add records, you can be pretty confident you don't have the right database structure.  Can you give a bit more information about what an Equipment Option is, and how it needs to be recorded?  I can't see quite what you're trying to do with the data you have.

Comment: @MikeChristie So when a customer orders they would chose a set "Order option", each Order option has a different number of equipment that comes with. (We don't normally sell items individually, but rather as a set, with customers needing varying sets, or options.) The **Equipment per Option** table pretty much shows what pieces of equipment come with each option. What I'm trying to do is were we to add a piece of equipment via the **Equipment** table form said equipment would appear as a new column on the **Equipment per Option** table automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find yourself having to add columns in order to handle simple transactions, it is a sign the db design is missing something.

Given your Equipment table:

```
Equipment Table
     Id   Equipment     Price
      1    Hose        $1.00 
      2    Shovel      $2.00 
      3    Hoe         $3.00
```

A bundle of these would have a name and probably a price:

```
EquipmentBundle
     Id   Name             Price
      1   Hoe And Hose      ...
      2   H-S-H Pkg         ...
```

Then a table to associate certain equipment records with a given bundle:

```
EquipmentBundleItems
     Id   EquipmentId    Quantity    
      1      1              2       ; Bundle 1 has 2 hoses
      1      3              1       ;  and 1 hoe
      2      1              3       ; Bundle 2 has 3 hoses
      2      2              2       ;   and 2 shovels
      2      3              1       ;   and 1 hoe
```

Presumably all current equipment is already in the Equipment items table, creating a new Bundle is just a matter of creating a new `EquipmentBundle` record and associating the related items with it via the `EquipmentBundleItems` table.